# TypeOrm many-to-many relationship error with oracle database

Tags: typescript, oracle, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

1. I trying to retreive many-to.many relationship data from a oracle database.
2. The database is already created and have alot of data.
3. the database structure is: please see the attachement
   [database_table_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eT2i.png)

4.My entity classes

```
@Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKER' })
export class CASEWORKER {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  CASEWORKERID: string;

  @Column()
  CASEWORKERNAME: string;

  @Column()
  ISACTIVE: string;

  @Column()
  TIME_STAMP: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => CASEWORKERGROUP, (CASEWORKERGROUP) => CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP)
  @JoinTable()
  CASEWORKERGROUPS: CASEWORKERGROUP[];
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKERGROUP' })
export class CASEWORKERGROUP {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  CASEWORKERGROUPID: string;

  @Column()
  CASEWORKERGROUPNAME: string;

  @Column()
  TIME_STAMP: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => CASEWORKER, (CASEWORKER) => CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP)
  CASEWORKERS: CASEWORKER[];

}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP' })
export class CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  CASEWORKERID: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  CASEWORKERGROUPID: string;

  @Column()
  TIME_STAMP: Date;
}
```

5. When I try to run the project I get following error - only when I to add tags for realation.

```
[Nest] 11604  - 08.04.2023 11.53.34   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database (regimeDBConnection). Retrying (1)...
TypeORMError: Entity metadata for **CASEWORKER#CASEWORKERGROUPS** was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
    at C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1089:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1079:34)
    at C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
    at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\connection\ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
    at DataSource.buildMetadatas (C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:685:13)
    at DataSource.initialize (C:\Development\lbst-api-demo\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:253:13)
[Nest] 11604  - 08.04.2023 11.53.34   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Entity metadata for CASEWORKER#CASEWORKERGROUPS was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building the connection wrong. For a bi-directional relation, you need to specify a valid property. you need to change this:

```
@ManyToMany(() => CASEWORKERGROUP, (CASEWORKERGROUP) => CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP)
  @JoinTable()
  CASEWORKERGROUPS: CASEWORKERGROUP[];
```

To this,
here `CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP` should refer to a valid relation of `CASEWORKERGROUP` entity. so the correct relation would be

```
@ManyToMany(() => CASEWORKERGROUP, (CASEWORKERGROUP) => CASEWORKERGROUP.CASEWORKERS)
  @JoinTable()
  CASEWORKERGROUPS: CASEWORKERGROUP[];
```

And for the `CASEWORKERGROUP` entity

```
@ManyToMany(() => CASEWORKER, (CASEWORKER) => CASEWORKER.CASEWORKERGROUPS)
  CASEWORKERS: CASEWORKER[];
```

Comment: Hi Akash,

1.I tried your solution , but without luck

getting followiing error:

[Nest] 12652  - 10.04.2023 11.01.12   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database (regimeDBConnection). Retrying (1)...
TypeORMError: Entity metadata for CASEWORKER#CASEWORKERGROUPS was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

2. is there something wrong with my intersect entity name? do you have other suggestions?

@Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP' })
export class CASEWORKER_CASEWORKERGROUP {
 }

Comment: can you share your updated entities?

Comment: import { Column, Entity, ManyToMany, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Caseworker } from './caseworker.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKERGROUP' })
export class CaseworkerGroup {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  caseworkerGroupId: string;

  @Column()
  caseworkerGroupName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'TIME_STAMP' })
  timestamp: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => Caseworker, (Caseworker) => Caseworker.caseworkerGroups)
  caseworkers: Caseworker[];
}

Comment: @Entity({ name: 'CASEWORKER' })
export class Caseworker {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  caseworkerId: string;

  @Column()
  caseworkerName: string;

  @Column()
  isActive: string;

  @Column({ name: 'TIME_STAMP' })
  timestamp: Date;

  @ManyToMany(
    () => CaseworkerGroup,
    (CaseworkerGroup) => CaseworkerGroup.caseworkers,
  )
  @JoinTable()
  caseworkerGroups: CaseworkerGroup[];
}

Comment: I'm soryy but dont know how to add in formated or longer text?